# Cognito "redirect URL" using Android SDK

Tags: android, amazon-cognito

I'm not sure how to set up the sign up redirect URL for Cognito (non-federated account handling).

In the sample application (https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonCognitoAuthDemo) the default URL is set to:

**demoapp://www.loginactivity.com/mainactivity**

Javadoc says:

> Required to allow Amazon Cognito Auth to correctly redirect after successful
>            *      authentication.
>            *      Must be a fully-qualified domain name and include the scheme.
>            *      Must one of the allowed redirect uri for sign-in in the User-Pool.
>            *      This is the redirect uri for SignUp and Forgot-Password processes.

Let's split this down. What is:

- demoapp ?
- www.loginactivity.com ?
- mainactivity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized later that this was an optional feature when using a certain cognito library, com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoauth. The redirect URL could be registered on the client side and then mirrored on the server side (callback to the client). The client would then open a web browser with some built-in page for cognito.

Answer (score 1):

in your AndroidManifest.xml file configure the schema, host and path.

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!--TODO Add sign-in redirect URI as intent filter-->

            <!--This intent filter is an example for sign-in redirect URI: demoapp://demo.cognitoauth.com/signin-->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="demoapp" android:host="demo.cognitoauth.com" android:path="/signin"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>
```